# undefined method `content' for #<Note id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seem this question posted before but the normal "add :content to model" doesn't work for my situation. I have already added it and the error still occurs.

This a modified version of a codecademy project if it looks familiar.

Model

```
 class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :notes do |t|
        t.text :content
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
 end
```

Controller

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @notes = Note.all
    end

    def new
       @note = Note.new
    end

    def create
       @note = Note.new(note_params)
           if @note.save
               redirect_to '/notes'
           else
               render 'new'
           end
    end

    private
    def note_params
       params.require(:note).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

     root 'notes#index'
     get "notes" => "notes#index"
     get "notes/new" => "notes#new"
     post "notes" => "notes#create"
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Notes</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="notes">
  <div class="container">

    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
        <div class="note">
        <p class="content"><%= note.content %></p>
        <p class="time"><%= note.created_at %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'New Note', "notes/new" %>

  </div>
</div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Notes</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="create">
  <div class="container">

    <%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :note %><br>
            <%= f.text_area :content %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Create" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can figure out why I am still getting this error after :content is already in the model, that would be awesome!

P.S. First post so sorry if it is terrible.

Comment: do `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to run the migration. Restart the server and try again.

Comment: I have tried this multiple times to no avail.

Comment: After running the migration( take care of environment), if you run `rails c`, can you create Note, and use `content` method?

Comment: It seems that `#<Note id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>` doesn't have content field, is your `t.text :content` added after you have ran `db:migrate` command ?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord creates the method `content` on the model by inspecting the columns in the database. Since the method is undefined, I think you may have forgotten to run migrations.

Possible reasons the column isn't present:

- You aren't connecting to the same database when running migrations and when running the app. For example, you could be running in different environments.
- Your migration doesn't actually add the needed column. Check your migration.

Possible ways of checking:

- Inspect the database "by hand" to confirm that the column is actually present.

Comment: I have run migrations multiple times and the error still occurs.

Comment: If you start a rails console and write for example `Note.new.content`, do you get the no method error?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure I am typing the command in correctly. I have ruby set up on windows with a .bat file. I am also very new to ruby and rails. I tried typing 'Note.new.content','rails Note.new.content', and also 'ruby Note.new.content'. They all came up with errors saying the command didn't exist or that the file didn't exist. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know how to setup ruby or rails on Windows, but if you have a `rails` executable, you should be able to write `rails console` to start a console. In that console you can write `Note.new.content`. If that also throws a `NoMethod` error, you know that your database hasn't been properly migrated.

Comment: Yep, NoMethod error. Where do I go from here? I have already performed migrations multiple times with 'rake db:migrate'. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: There may be several possible issues. Are you connecting to the correct database? Usually, rails chooses which db to connect to based upon the current environment name. The environment is usually something like *development* or *production* or *testing*. Development is default in most cases. It's possible you are migrating one database and running the app against another. Can you inspect your database "by hand" to confirm it has actually been migrated? Are you sure your migrations are correct?